# Precedence of css "current" class over a:visited

Tags: html, css

The following test.html shows that the "current" class overrides "a:visited" for font-size, but not for color. Can you please offer an explanation and source of documentation for this behavior? I did search myself but could not find anything. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      a:visited { font-size: 10px; color: purple; }
      .current { font-size: 50px; color: red; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/test.html" class="current">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the "current" class overrides "a:visited" for font-size.

That's not what's happening. The font-size setting on `a:visited` is being ignored, because it can be exploited to detect a users browsing history, violating their privacy.

The CSS specs don't describe this exact details of which properties are honoured and which ignored. [All they say](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#example-0fcef6cd) is

> Since it is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the :link and :visited pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the user’s consent, UAs may treat all links as unvisited links or implement other measures to preserve the user’s privacy while rendering visited and unvisited links differently.

Answer (score 1):

Additional details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Basically you can set only colour-related properties:
color, background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color, border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color, column-rule-color, outline-color, text-decoration-color, and text-emphasis-color.